# Timeout while Firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, deployment, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to deploy my Firebase functions to Firebase but my cmd gives me the following information:

```
i   runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+   runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
!   missing necessary APIs. Enabling now...
i   functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i   functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i   functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
....after a few minutes....
Error: Timed out waiting for APIs to enable. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This issue is related to an [ongoing issue](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17026) involving project creation. Keep an eye on the status page for resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `firebase deploy --only hosting` IT WORKS!

I will wait a reply for the opened issue and update here if something changes.